# Arduino Uno R3 + WiFi Shield + Any Temperature sensor

Tags: sensors, arduino-uno, omnet++

I am doing a project in WSN and I have got my Arduino UNO R3 with WiFi shield. Now that I have tested the basic configurations as listed in the arduino website and all are working fine. Now I have to connect any 2 temperature sensors and make them collect the data and then feed it to a simulator ( Omnet++ Preferable) securely. I have few clarifications in this, please clarify.

1. Should I Upgrade the WiFi shield ? Is it necessary?
2. If I want to enable a encryption method for the sensors passing data through WiFi shield connecting to simulator running in pc/laptop , any best practices to be followed?

Your answers to my questions are appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by *"upgrade the WiFi shield"*?

Comment: Hi, I meant upgradring the firmware of WiFi Shield. Somehow I am able to update the firmware of WiFi shield successfully. Thanks

Comment: One more clarification in Omnet++ simulation is , I am often coming across HIL concept. Can someone please explain what is HIL concept and INET framework ?